# How do I write a regular expression for Integers in JavaCC?

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

How do I write a regular expression for Integers and Identifiers:

Integers are represented by a string of one or more digits 0-9 and
may start with a minus sign "-", e.g. 246, -789. Unless its 0. Numbers cannot start with a 0, e.g. 0123, this is illegal.

Identifiers can be a string of letters, digits, or underscore ("_")  beginning with a letter. Identifiers cannot be reserved words.

This is what I have so far, which is not correct. How would I write the regular expression as specified above in JavaCC.

```
TOKEN :
    {
        < #LETTER: ["a"-"z","A"-"Z"] >
    |   < DIGIT: ["0"] | (["1"-"9"])+>
    |   < IDENTIFIER: < LETTER > | < DIGIT > | (< LETTER > | ["_"]) >
    }
```

Comment: What is your issue? It's not clear what you want to achieve at all and what does "Am I correct?" mean here? Are you programming in java or are you parsing java code because I don't understand the meaning of "reserved words".

Comment: Sorry, I will edit it now. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I have edited it, thanks. This is for JavaCC not java by the way. This is to do with compiler construction. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @BartKiers ....

Comment: What is "not correct" about your solution? In other words, what does it recognise which it shouldn't recognise and/or fail to recognise when it should recognise? Answering those questions will probably help you solve your problem.

Comment: For dealing with reserved words, see the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

There's some lack of clarity in your question.  But something like the following will likely work

```
TOKEN :
    {
      < #LETTER: ["a"-"z","A"-"Z"] >
    | < #DIGIT: ["0"-"9"]>
    | < IDENTIFIER: <LETTER> ( <LETTER> | <DIGIT> | "_")* >
    | < INTEGER: "0" | ("-")? ["1"-"9"] (<DIGIT>)* >
    }
```

Of course IDENTIFIER may match reserved words, so you need to deal with that aspect yet.  See the FAQ for the usual approaches.

If this is an assignment, be sure to cite this answer.

Comment: Thanks very much! Also, for Identifier, why do you use <...(<LETTER> | <DIGIT> | "_")*>? @TheodoreNorvell

Comment: I didn't. I used `<LETTER> (<LETTER> | <DIGIT> | "_")*`. And that is because you said 'Identifiers can be a string of letters, digits, or [sic] underscore ("_") beginning with a letter.'